# Count Categorical Column values mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database which contains a column named `Grade`, all of the Grades that are in `Grade` are either `A` or `B` or `C` :

```
Grade = [A,A,A,B]
```

what i want to do is to count the total number of grades and each class of `Grade` separately, so the output would be like :

```
Total Grades | A | B | C
-------------------------
      4      | 3 | 1 | 0
```

i can do this using multiple `SELECT`'s and joins, but what is the best way to do it? note that i want the output represented in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*), sum(grade = 'A') as a, sum(grade = 'B') as b,
       sum(grade = 'C') as c
from t;
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the number of Categories in the Column just use:

```
SELECT grade, count(*) as Count FROM t GROUP BY 1
```